# JAVA POST method doesn't POST to page

Tags: java, android, json, post, httpurlconnection

I am attempting to POST **JSON data** to a server. Using [this page](http://danielnugent.blogspot.com/2015/06/updated-jsonparser-with.html) as a template since it uses the modern `HttpURLConnection`.

Though I have tried multiple ways, this only returns the actual page's HTML pre-post. It doesn't actually post the **JSON Data** (passed as string to the method) to the page.

I tried using my **JSON Data** as a *JSONObject*, however the `DataOutputStream` doesn't like that.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
HttpURLConnection conn;
DataOutputStream wr;
StringBuilder result;
URL urlObj;
JSONObject jObj = null;

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String data) {

    urlObj = new URL("MY URL HERE");

    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+data.length());
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.connect();

    wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(data);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();


    //Receive the response from the server
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    conn.disconnect();
    jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
    return jObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code. It is working in my app.

```
public JSONObject getResponse(String data) {
    try {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(data);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            builder.append("{status: \"Unable to connect to server.\"}");
        }
        Log.e("JSONService.java", builder.toString());
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        return object;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("JSONService.java", Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        try {
            object.put(STATUS, "Exception " +  ex.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("JSONService.java", Log.getStackTraceString(ex));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Make sure your application has `INTERNET` permissions in manifest file and make sure that URL is correct.